# Accessing web.config file from an external dll in C#

Tags: c#, web-services, model-view-controller, web-config

I am doing a product licensing application using MVC and Webservices.
Here if a product(win/web application) needs to perform license validation, then it will call the web service I have implemented in my licensing application. And it works fine. 
If a product want to register with this licensing application, Some code is needed to be deployed in every client product, such as code to invoke the web service, do encryption and send details to renewal page if license expired. 
To include these changes to every client product, I am planning to create a dll that implements these many logic and deploy to each product. Here I want to access web.config/app.config of every client application from my dll and add some keys within in  tag. Is thing possible to access another application web.config file from an external dll  that has been deployed to that application?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you have your application installed at a number of client sites that contains a config file. You now want to install a secondary application that will access that config file? A config file is simply an xml file, so as long as your application can reach the config location you want to read, then I don't see why not.

Comment: Yes, You read it correctly, But how can I access the location of web.config and open it  from a class library?

Comment: I'd open the config file as text and use that to create an XML doc. Then use either linqtoxml or xpath to get your app setting with the details you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed, below is an example of how to load a web.config and access the app settings section.

For this local example, I've moved a web.config to C:\Web.config and are using Linq XML.

```
 using System.Xml.Linq;

 XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("C:\\web.config"); //Path to your config here!

 XElement appSettingsNode = xdoc.Elements().First()
      .Elements().FirstOrDefault(f=> f.Name == "appSettings");

 foreach (XNode node in appSettingsNode.Nodes())
 {
      var currentSetting = node.ToString(); //Here check the contents for setting you need
 }
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for the answer, But my web.config file path is not hard coded, I want to read it like server.map or something. It not working

Comment: That is just an example! That's why its says in the comments "Path to your config here"....Where you get the path to your config from is up to you!! You could keep the path to the other config in your primary app config! You asked how to access a config.. not where to store the path to the config!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, But my web.config file path is not hard coded, I want to read it like server.map or something. 

XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Web.config"));.MapPath("~/Web.config"));

Here showing error like System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath is not existing. Beacuse i am trying to access it from class library, .cs file

Comment: I think you are missing the point here. You are getting the path to your config wrong! My code can be changed to "XDocument.Load(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Web.config"));.MapPath("~/Web.config"))).. But if you have the path wrong, then that's a different issue!